# Parsing twitter @name with regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter

I'm trying to parse twitter name tags using javascript and was wondering if this regex would do the trick. I think most of this works, but am just wondering if I'm using the $1 and $2 properly. Can people confirm that this is right and if so, generally explain what the $1 and $2 represent?

```
str = str.replace(/([^\w])\@([\w\-]+)/gm,'$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're using [the `$n` right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace#section_5):

> *$n* or *$nn*
>   Where *n* or *nn* are decimal digits, inserts the nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the first argument was a RegExp object.

So your `$1` will be replaced with what matched `[^\w]` and `$2` will be replaced with what matched `[\w\-]+`. However, I think you want a bit more in your first group so that you can properly match strings like `"@pancakes"`, a `(^|\W+)` would serve you better:

```
str = str.replace(/(^|\W+)\@([\w\-]+)/gm,'$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>');
```

You might want to read up on [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

And, thanks to Kobi, you could use a simpler regular expression but you'll have to change change your replacements a little bit:

```
str = str.replace(/\B@([\w-]+)/gm, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" target="_blank">@$1</a>');
```

And you don't need to escape the hyphen when it can't be mistaken for a range indicator.

Comment: Thanks. What exactly does `(^|\W+)` do?

Comment: `\B@([\w\-]+)` should have the same effect - you want to match where there isn't a word boundary, which is the same as checking if the previous letter wasn't alphanumeric.

Comment: @cfarm54: `^` matches the beginning of the string, `|` means "or", and `\W+` matches one or more non-word characters (`\W+` is a shorter way of saying `[^\w]+`).

Comment: @Kobi: Right, thanks. Too many subtly different regex flavors. That would also change the replacement patterns. I'll add an update with that pattern.

Comment: @cfarm54: There is some good documentation on JavaScript regexes here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @Kobi so if I understand you correctly how does my original first block differ from `\B`?

Comment: @cfarm54: Your's would miss things like `"@y-x"` and using `\B` expresses the intent better than my `(^|\W+)`.

Comment: @mu i'm ok with no "@y-x" because I dont think this is allowed in twitter anyway (correct me if i'm wrong). I'm more concerned about why I should use `\B` instead of what I have `[^\w]`

Comment: @cfarm54: I mean an `@stuff` that appears at the beginning of a string rather than in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

The first group, ([^\w]), needs to be optional, so try this: /([^\w])?\@([\w-]+)/gm

A great online tool for testing a regex can be found here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Mu is too short is right, (^|\W+) would be better for the first group.

Comment: I'm trying to say that you can identify the @name with not an alphanumeric char. Mainly because if someone types xx@gmail.com, then it won't count this.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. For testing, use the tool I tool linked to run the regex against different strings you want to match and/or not match.